# Undefined result from function (html script)

Tags: html

I'm trying to calculate total pay from inputs given by the user in an html script. I keep getting an undefined result for total pay. I've tried calling the calculate_pay function from the second script tags but that didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Chapter 4 Assignment</title>
<script>



function input_output(netPay)
{

var hoursWorked = prompt("How many hours have you worked?","");
var payRate = prompt ("What is your hourly pay rate?","");
var taxRate = prompt ("What is the tax rate for your state? ex. 11 for 11%","");
var br = "<br>";


document.write("Hours worked: "+hoursWorked+br);
document.write("Pay rate: "+payRate+br);
document.write("Tax rate: "+taxRate+br);
document.write("Total pay: "+netPay+br);
}

function calculate_pay(hoursWorked,payRate,taxRate)
{
var taxRate = taxRate/100;
var grossPay = (hoursWorked*taxRate);
var netPay = grossPay - (taxRate * grossPay);
return netPay;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

input_output();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried calling the calculate_pay function in input_output like this:

```
function input_output(netPay)
{

var hoursWorked = prompt("How many hours have you worked?","");
var payRate = prompt ("What is your hourly pay rate?","");
var taxRate = prompt ("What is the tax rate for your state? ex. 11 for 11%","");
var br = "<br>";

calculate_pay();

document.write("Hours worked: "+hoursWorked+br);
document.write("Pay rate: "+payRate+br);
document.write("Tax rate: "+taxRate+br);
document.write("Total pay: "+netPay+br);
}
```

As well as calling it in the second script tags and both at the same time but it still returns undefined.

Comment: You are calling `input_output`, however, you defined `netPay` as an argument and never call `calculate_pay`

Comment: You need to call `calculate_pay` as you're returning `netPay` in `calculate_pay` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calling the `input_output()` function, which prompts the user for `hoursWorked`, `payRate`, and `taxRate`, but never calculates anything. The parameter to `input_output()`, `netPay`, is probably misplaced. You should call your function `calculate_pay()` to actually get that value.

The last line in your first function should be

```
document.write("Total pay: " + calculate_pay(hoursWorked,payRate,taxRate) + br);
```

But before even getting there, you must take care to convert the input values from `String` to a `Number` using parseFloat. That is, for each prompt that you have, do the following:

```
var hoursWorked = parseFloat(
  prompt("How many hours have you worked?","")
);
```

Whatever the user types will always be a `String`, so always remember to convert those string values to an actual `Number` using the `parseFloat()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this instead:

```
function input_output() {...} // get rid of the input parameter
```

Add this after the var taxRate line:

```
var netPay = calculate_pay(hoursWorked, payRate, taxRate);
```